# Reset Document ID prefix in SharePoint Online in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, document-id

I am looking for a way to reset the Document ID prefix for all documents in my SharePoint Online tenant in PowerShell.

I have got 4000 site collections and customer prefers to use new prefix in 'documentID' for all documents already in these site collections.

Can you please throw some light on how to accomplish this?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't think it's possible to reset the Document ID prefix through powershell in SharePoint online.

All I can find is to change the Document ID prefix:

```
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "docid_enabled" -Value "1"
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "docid_msft_hier_siteprefix" -Value $DocIDPrefix
```

You need to go to site settings-> Document ID settings, choose Reset all Document IDs in this Site Collection to begin with these characters manually.